# Character set on Solaris

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, console, solaris

I have a simple java program that prints out some special characters

```
System.out.println("á");
System.out.println("é");
System.out.println("í");
System.out.println("ó");
System.out.println("ú");
```

When I run this code on a windows 7 machine, it prints to the console the correct characters. 
I now deploy it to a soloris machine and run the code.It looks like this 
    Ã¡ 
    Ãº 
    Ã­ 
    Ã³ 
    Ã©

I have tried running the jar with the commands 
    java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8

How can I get the special characters to print out in solaris?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a UTF-8 locale installed and configured for your terminal. I'm not as familiar with setting this up on Solaris, however these links might help you get started:

- [Customizing and Creating Solaris Locales](http://developers.sun.com/dev/gadc/techtips/locale_customization.html)
- [How to manually add locale pkgs on Solaris 10](http://www.netlinxinc.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=50%3ahow-to-manually-add-locale-pkgs-on-solaris-10&catid=12%3asolaris&Itemid=2)
- [en_US.utf-8 locale in Solaris 10](http://www.runningunix.com/2008/07/en_usutf-8-locale-in-solaris-10/)